# Delete worksheet if cells are empty

Tags: vba, excel

This would be a very simple question.
But I am not sure why this is not working in my excel vba code.

```
Sheets("I- ABC").Select
If IsEmpty(Range("A3").Value) = True And _
    IsEmpty(Range("A4").Value) = True And _
    IsEmpty(Range("A5").Value) = True And _
    IsEmpty(Range("A6").Value) = True Then
    Sheets("I- ABC").Delete
End If
```

Comment: `If Application.CountA(Range("A3:A6")) = 0 Then`

Comment: There is no error or display alert. My other steps in the Macro runs smoothly. But not deleting the sheet when these cells are empty.

Answer (score 0):

What type of error do you get? I tried this code and Excel displays only warning message:

[image: Warning message]

You can avoid this message by adding:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
```

and

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

at the beginning and at the end of your code respectively.

--Edited code

```
Sub Example()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

With Sheets("I- ABC")
    If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range("A3:A6")) = 0 Then
        .Delete
    End If
End With

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: There is no error or display alert. 
All the other steps running smoothly.

Comment: So, what's the problem? Doesn't your code remove blank sheets as expected? Could you describe your issue more accurately?

Comment: There is no error or display alert. My other steps in the Macro runs smoothly. But not deleting the sheet when these cells are empty.

Comment: Hmm, the previous exapmle work on my Excel. However, please try the updated code using the CountA function as Tim Williams suggested.

Comment: Still not working. Just to add, even though there are no data in these cells, there are different formatting (like back groud colour).

Comment: Can you check what the funcion COUNTA returns if you enter it directly in the worksheet?

Comment: @azera It will work only when cells are truly empty or Blank. For Example if I write some characters and then delete them but if cursor is in between then even alternatives suggested by me also may not work.

Comment: what else is in the cells?

Answer (score 0):

Try Similiar to This

```
Sub Test()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
     Columns("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

PS: It works for me and deletes rows containg empty cells in `A:A``

Approach Suggested by @Tim Williams also works for me  as per following code in my situation

```
Sub Test6()
  Dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long
  Set r = ActiveSheet.Range("A3:A6")
  rows = r.rows.Count
  For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete
  Next
End Sub
```

It works even if we use `Application` instead of `WorksheetFunction`

Comment: @pnuts I have gone by the comments which were appearing on this question and remembered the situation which worked for me. Since by the time of my mentioning the alternative there was no indication of the fact that OP has got any success. I did try OP code it did not work. Is sugessting alternatives wrong here.

Comment: @pnuts OP code gives Run Time error on the line ~Sheets("I- ABC").Select` . Since I am also engaged in some other important work, I could not go for detailed analysis.

Comment: @pnuts please see my latest edit of the post. Hope it satisfies your requirement that a person answering the question should analyse the code, first consider the alternatives suggested and then only put has additional answer. I am sorry If I have hurt any one feelings.

Answer (score 0):

If `If Application.CountA(Range("A3:A6")) = 0 Then` is not working as Tim suggested then that means the cells have blank spaces or unprintable characters.

Try this

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim pos As Long

    With Sheets("I- ABC")
        pos = Len(Trim(.Range("A3").Value)) + _
              Len(Trim(.Range("A4").Value)) + _
              Len(Trim(.Range("A5").Value)) + _
              Len(Trim(.Range("A6").Value))

        If pos = 0 Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            .Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        Else
            MsgBox "The cells are not empty"
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this program on a new sheet, it gives a message `Cells not empty`. I came accross a program on the web for similiar type of application "Macro to delete a sheet if cell is empty"<http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=30231>. I am not so strong in VBA and find it difficult to interpose Tim code there otherwise program is functional.

Comment: If it says cells are not empty then they are not :D. Go to those cells and if you do not see anything then manually press delete and try again.

Comment: I have checked all cells from A3 oA6 individually using following code fragment as sample `If IsEmpty(Range("A3").Value) = True Then
      MsgBox "Cell A3 is empty"
   End If` I am getting correct results from Message Box. like cell C4 is empty and not for others but at the end same message that Cells are not empty appears on Message Box.

Comment: I have uploaded the test file used by me  - test2409 on the following link<https://www.dropbox.com/s/z6jmfxbyo6zgzj6/test2409.xlsm?dl=0>

Comment: My code works correctly on your workbook. You get cells not empty because A3 and A5 are not empty. OPs request is that if "ALL" cells are empty then delete the sheet which my code does :)

Comment: Yes it works. I misunderstood OP requirements that if any cell in that range is empty. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

With skkakkar's idea expanded.

```
Sub Hello()
    Dim rng As Range
    Application.DisplayAlerts = 0
    On Error GoTo er
    Set rng = Range("A3:A6").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 23)
    Exit Sub
er:     MsgBox "ActiveSheet.Delete" 'delete sheet
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If the spaces are the issue, then you can try this code:

```
Public Sub RemoveIfEmpty()

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With Sheets("I- ABC")
        If Trim(.Range("A3") & .Range("A4") & .Range("A5") & .Range("A6")) = "" Then
            .Delete
        End If
    End With

    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```